# Java OutOfMemoryError when building AOSP 10

Tags: java, android-source

I want to build Android 10 from source code and followed the official instructions. In order to get started, I want to simply build it for the emulator. However, the build keeps failing and I get the following error:

```
[11177/12864] rm -rf "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/out" "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/srcjars" "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/stubsDir" && mkdir -p "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/out" "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/srcjars" "out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/stubsDir" && out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/zipsync -d out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/srcjars -l out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/srcjars/list -f "*.java" out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/framework-javastream-protos/gen/frameworks/base/core/proto/android/privacy.srcjar [...]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs-stubs.srcjar out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs_api.txt out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs_removed.txt out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/private.txt out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs_annotations.zip out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-versions.xml out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs_api.xml out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/api-stubs-docs_last_released_api.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:68)
    at java.base/java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:341)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:794)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:818)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.convertBytes(LoadTextUtil.java:640)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.getTextByBinaryPresentation(LoadTextUtil.java:555)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.getTextByBinaryPresentation(LoadTextUtil.java:545)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.loadText(LoadTextUtil.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.loadText(LoadTextUtil.java:503)
    at com.intellij.mock.MockFileDocumentManagerImpl.getDocument(MockFileDocumentManagerImpl.java:53)
    at com.intellij.psi.AbstractFileViewProvider.getDocument(AbstractFileViewProvider.java:194)
    at com.intellij.psi.AbstractFileViewProvider$VirtualFileContent.getText(AbstractFileViewProvider.java:484)
    at com.intellij.psi.AbstractFileViewProvider.getContents(AbstractFileViewProvider.java:174)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.loadTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:204)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:709)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.getClasses(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$Companion.findClassInPsiFile(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$Companion.access$findClassInPsiFile(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:246)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.findPsiClassInVirtualFile(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.access$findPsiClassInVirtualFile(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClasses$1$$special$$inlined$forEachClassId$lambda$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClasses$1$$special$$inlined$forEachClassId$lambda$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.index.JvmDependenciesIndexImpl$traverseDirectoriesInPackage$1.invoke(JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.index.JvmDependenciesIndexImpl$traverseDirectoriesInPackage$1.invoke(JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.index.JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.search(JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.index.JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.traverseDirectoriesInPackage(JvmDependenciesIndexImpl.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.index.JvmDependenciesIndex$DefaultImpls.traverseDirectoriesInPackage$default(JvmDependenciesIndex.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClasses$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClasses$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.findClasses(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:147)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFinderImpl.findClasses(PsiElementFinderImpl.java:45)
```

When searching for a solution, I only find problems related to jack-server. As I understand jack is [not used in recent builds anymore](https://source.android.com/setup/build/jack). Also, I tried to reduce the number of build threads using `m -j1` without success.

Here is some info about my setup: 4 core CPU, 8GB RAM

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-142-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-14.04.6-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ1D.200205.002
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
```

Comment: This should help
[link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html)

Comment: In `/build/core/config.mk`, I changed the line `APICHECK_COMMAND := $(JAVA) -Xmx4g -jar $(APICHECK) --no-banner --compatible-output=yes` to the same but with ´-Xmx5500m`. That didn't help. Does anyone know how much is needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research I found a solution. During build, `/prebuilts/jdk/jdk9/linux-x86/bin/java` is being called without the `-Xmx` option. When typing

```
$ /prebuilts/jdk/jdk9/linux-x86/bin/java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize'
```

into the commandline, I found out that a maximum of only about 2 GB of heap were allowed.

### Solution

Because I don't know in which file java is being called, I just set the heap size to 4 GB using an enviroment variable:

```
$ export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"
```

Java will automatically pick this option up.

---

**(Optional)** I also increased the swap size from 8 GB to 20 GB.

Comment: I appended .bashrc file with: export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m